# Dividing two Ulong integers outputs wrong result

Tags: c#, math, factorial, catalan

I am writing a program for Catalan number. So here is the formula for that:

---

### [image: This is the formula]

---

I decided to use the middle part of the formula, because the other parts are too abstract for my knowledge (maybe I slept too much in math classes).
Actually my program works fine for `n = 0;`,`n = 5;`, `n = 10;` But if I enter `n = 15;` - here comes the boom - the output is `2` when it should be `9694845`.
So here is my child:

```
using System;
namespace _8_Numbers_of_Catalan
{
    class CatalanNumbers
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("n: ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Catalan({0})", n);
            //calculating the Catan number from the formula 
            // Catan(n) = [(2*n)!]/[(n+1)! * n!]
            Console.WriteLine((factorial(2 * n)) / (factorial(n + 1) * factorial(n)));
        }//finding the factorial
        private static ulong factorial(int n)
        {
            ulong fact = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                fact *= (ulong)i;
            }
            return fact;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Thank you in advance for understanding me if there is something obviously wrong. I am new in programming.*

Comment: Use the third formula which avoids the overflow which happens with the 2nd one. Look it up on wikipedia, the PI is like SIGMA but just with multiplying. Translates 1:1 into code.

Comment: This is a naive implementation of factorial.  It'll be inaccurate and inefficient.  Better to go with lngamma function and memoization.  I'd wonder if there was a recursion relation C(n) and C(n-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are performing calculation of these using integer variables that can contain at most 64 bits.

Your call to `factorial(15 * 2)` is **30!** which would result in a value of

```
265,252,859,812,191,058,636,308,480,000,000
```

Much more than fits in a 64 bit integer variable:

```
18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).
```

The options you have are to use a [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type (slow) or a `double` (up to a maximum value of `1.7976931348623157E+308`). Which means you will loose some precision, that may or may not be relevant.

Another option you have is to use an algorithm to approximate the value of large factorials using an asymptotic approximation such as the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) used by Mathematica.

You may also want to check out some existing online resources for calculation of big factorials in .NET

As a last **but not least** option (and I have not thoroughly checked) it seems likely to me that specific algorithms exists that allow you to calculate (or approximate to a sufficient accuracy and precision) a [`Catalan number`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Catalan_numbers).

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter could have commented on what in his/her opinion is wrong with this answer, so that I am given the opportunity to improve it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

you should use a System.Numerics.BigInteger for this. (add System.Numerics as reference in your project).

```
private static BigInteger factorial(int n)
{
     BigInteger fact = 1;
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     {
        fact *= i;
     }
     return fact;
 }

 // output: 9694845
```